# How to use 'Any' in AsQueryable methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to get my query to output all data, if given any parameter 'name' and 'price' or name only. I tried using 'Any' parameter but it gives me -- Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to -- error.

I was previously using 'FirstOrDefault' but that was only outputting the first record details.

Is their another function i can use or look into?

User class:

```
  public database_ab getData(Query query)
    {

        var data = db.database_ab.AsQueryable();

        if (query.name != null)
        {
            data = data.Where(c => c.Name == query.name);
        }

        if (query.price != null)
        {
            data = data.Where(c => c.Price == query.price);
        }

        return data.Any();
    }
```

Items Controller:

```
public HttpResponseMessage getData([FromUri] Query query)
    {
        User layer = new User();
       // if (User.IsInRole("user"))
       // {
            var result = layer.getData(query);
            if (result == null)
            {
                // return HttpResponseMessage
                var message = string.Format("No data was found");
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, message);
            }
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
       // }
    }
```

Many thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The call to `.Any()` returns a boolean value indicating whether or not any records were found.

If you want to return the actual records, try this:

- Change `return data.Any();` to `return data;`
- Change the return type on your method from `database_ab` to `IEnumerable<database_ab>`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response and help. I tried using IEnumerable method type before, but then I cannot search for two values such as api/item?name=key&price=23 and it outputs a blank page. Do i need to amend something in the items controller. Many thanks for your help

Comment: hi, I have tried it with List also but I am still experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply return the data variable object i.e.

```
public IEnumerable<database_ab> getData(Query query)
    {

        var data = db.database_ab.AsQueryable();

        if (query.name != null)
        {
            data = data.Where(c => c.Name == query.name);
        }

        if (query.price != null)
        {
            data = data.Where(c => c.Price == query.price);
        }

        return data;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response and help. I tried using IEnumerable method type before, but then I cannot search for two values such as api/item?name=key&price=23 and it outputs a blank page. Do i need to amend something in the items controller. Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The return type of the `Any` extension method is of type bool; it is intended to return true if some item of the collection matches some given criterion. Syntactically correct would be to just return `data` instead of `data.Any()`; perhaps this already solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should make two changes: first change the return type

```
//you are returning a single element
public database_ab getData(Query query)
```

to

```
//you are going to return many elements
public IEnumerable<database_ab> getData(Query query)
```

and consequently simply return your `data` object

```
return data;
}
```

The method `.Any()` means "Does *any* of the items in the collection satisfy this condition?", as in

```
var Coll = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
// is any element of Coll greater than 2 ?
var myCondition = Coll.Any(element => element > 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

`return data.Any();` Doesn't make any sense.

`Any()` returns boolean value based on your condition.

```
eg: data = data.Any(c => c.Name == query.name);
```

returns boolean values based on the result of the condition.

If you want to return all the data just do

```
return data;
```

or

```
return data.Tolist();  // if you want the result in list.
```